# Аккаунт разработчика | Apple | Украина

Tags: ios, apple

Доброе время суток!

Я живу в Украине, очень хочется получить аккаунт разработчика iOS, как его получить в Украине, что для этого нужно, и вообще, как это делается в этой стране?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно будет оформить долларовый счет в украинском банке чтобы оплатить с него счет (программа разработчика приложений стоит 100$ в год для физлиц). Идете сначала [сюда](https://developer.apple.com/), кликаете Member Center, дальше все интуитивно по подсказкам. Нужно будет выслать факсом требуемые реквизиты (там все обьяснят), в том числе Вашего счета, так что счет нужно оформить в первую очередь. После этого для Вам будет создан аккаунт на этом сайте и Вы получите доступ ко всем его возможностям а также к сайту [Itunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) где содержится управление приложениями и статистика. [Тут](http://www.iguides.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=43253) детально описано что нужно будет сделать дальше для того чтобы тестировать на устройствах Ваше приложение и публиковать его в Itunes.

Обсуждение вопросов по выводу денег в Украину:

[Обсуждение](http://dou.ua/forums/topic/4341/)

[Обсуждение1](http://dou.ua/lenta/articles/kak-zavesti-dengi-ot-zarubezhnyh-zakazchikov-v-ukrainu/)

[Обсуждение2](http://forum.finance.ua/topic89874.html)

[Обсуждение3](http://habrahabr.ru/company/payoneer/blog/166119/#comment_5736795)

[Обсуждение4](http://habrahabr.ru/post/95045/)

Comment: То есть никакой разницы между США и Украиной в создании аккаунта нет? А в каком банке лучше открывать счёт, и этот счёт будет накопительным, деньги с приложений будут перечислять на него?

Comment: Разницы нет. В любом который Вам нравится, мой личный опыт - не в привате. Сейчас допишу в ответ ссылки по поводу вывода денег, там же почерпнете информацию какой счет и как его оформлять

Comment: Посоветуйте как будет лучше, завести отдельный аккаунт для разработчика, или зарегистрировать уже имеющийся?

Comment: Уточните последний комментарий, потому что я не понимаю о чем Вы спрашиваете. Как можно зарегистрировать уже имеющийся аккаунт разработчика?

Comment: @AlexThumb Прошу прощения за неточность. У меня имеется обычный аккаунт для загрузки приложений с Mac App Store/App Store. На сколько мне известно можно на этот же аккаунт подключить аккаунт разработчика, или же всё таки лучше создать новый, именно для публикации приложений?

Comment: Аккаунт разработчика все же другое дело. Такая возможность вроде бы есть но лучше ничего не смешивайте чтобы не было проблем в будущем. Там масса заморочек поначалу и лучше чтобы Вы сами себя не запутывали

Comment: @AlexThumb, Если Вас не затруднит, могли бы Вы описать несколько "Заморочек", что бы быть готовым, и обратить внимание?

Comment: Я имею ввиду суету по поводу настройки аккаунта и сертификатов-профилей для тестирования и закачки в iTunes. Вероятное неудобство может быть если реквизиты Вашего пользовательского аккаунта сохранены в связку ключей, тогда на сайтах и при публикации через Xcode в поля могут подставляться неправильные реквизиты и сбивать Вас с толку

Comment: Мне кажется в Xcode5 эти проблемы с сертификатами свели к минимуму.